# Spss (mrScriptBasic) error handling obtain code where error occured

Tags: runtime, spss

Hello I am currently using IBM Spss, and I was wondering if there is a way when the code throws an exception to be able to obtain the line of code where the exception occurred? I am able to obtain the line number is there a way to access the stack of the lines that were executed and pull this information from there? Any ideas would be great Thank you in advance!

For Example:

```
Dim x, y, z
On Error Goto ErrorHandler
x = 30
y = 0
z = x / y 'would like to grab this code since this is where the error occurred
Exit 


ErrorHandler:
debug.Log(Err.Description + _
" error occurred on line number " + _
CText(Err.LineNumber))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to map the line number to the actual code unless you keep your own index, allowing for macro expansion etc.

What you can do, though, is to submit the code in blocks and catch the exception for that block, which narrows down the location.  In the limit, if each line is its own block, you will know exactly where the error occurred.

Comment: Thank you for your response @JKP I thought about the block and catching the exception, however for what I am trying to do I would need to obtain the actual code where the error occurred. You meantioned this could be possible with Macro expansion, are you referring to creating my own stack and keep track here? could you please give me more information?

Comment: If you don't have any macros, then just keeping an array of commands and executing them one by one is enough in simple cases, but if you have any INSERT or INCLUDE commands in the stream, you would be retrieving the INSERT/INCLUDE rather than the contents of the file.  You would have to intercept and read the contents of those files and parse out the commands.  Not easy.

Comment: With macros, you could run SET MPRINT ON and scrape the commands from the journal file.  Which makes me think that maybe looking at the tail of the journal file in case of an error might actually be the best strategy.  The journal file records all the actual syntax, assuming that journaling is on, and the file is flushed to disk after every command, so it is always current.  Here is what those contents might look like in case of an error,

Comment: foo a b c.
*>Error # 1.  Command name: foo
*>The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I had a question when you are referring the jornal are you referring to the script that I am working with? also instead of the macrowhat do you think about having a function that records each line of the routing and stores it in an array. When an error happen using err.line i beleive we can find the index where the error occured on that array and pull the error code?

Comment: I am referring to the standard Statistics journal file.  Statistics by default records every command and the error messages in that file.

Comment: As for getting the error line, you might still have to deal with INSERT and macro issues not to mention blocks of Python code.  I'm  nor sure where you are getting the line number from, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, however I think there might have been a misunderstand I am using the mrscriptbasic IBM SPSS not the Python version.

Comment: The Python code I was referring to would be in the syntax stream, not in your own code.  If you know that those streams will never include BEGIN PROGRAM blocks, then Python isn't an issue, but you would still have to worry about INSERT/INCLUDE and macros, MATRIX code and perhaps more esoteric things like INPUT PROGRAMS.